# Is it possible to reverse data binding when unchecking a tick box?

Tags: binding, coldfusion

I have a tick box and another input field that I want to bind the tick box to, this is easy.  Does anyone know if you can make it reverse what was done by the binding when the tick box is unticked. The code I have is below, any help on this would be great, thanks

```
<cfform>
<cfinput type="checkbox" name="TickBox" value="something">
<cfinput type="text" name="testing" bind="{TickBox}" value="whatever">
</cfform>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bind statement will fire any time the checkbox is interacted with (both checking and unchecking). You just have to determine how you're going to handle that action.

To get checked values from a Checkbox, try this:

```
<cfform>
    <cfinput type="checkbox" name="TickBox" value="something">
    <cfinput type="text" name="testing" bind="{TickBox.checked}" value="whatever">
</cfform>
```

You can then hook this into your own custom javascript (or as suggested in your comments) just your own javascript click events to handle the checking/unchecking of the box.

Comment: Hi Dan, what I've got above works in terms of writing 'something' to the text field, but if I uncheck it does nothing. I'm thinking about doing this using Javascript instead but if you've got any ideas, great.

Comment: I adjusted my answer above to take that into account. Doesn't do exactly what your original does, but does get you the checked value of the box.